# join list with linq-to-sql query

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of MyObject that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject{
  public int FruitID {get;set;}
  public string FruitName {get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> TheList = new List<MyObject>();
```

This list is populated with a linq-to-sql query. I'm looking to create a join between this list and a table that contains FruitID as its foreign key.

The table HarvestTimes looks like this:

```
FruitID   |   HarvestDatetime  |   RipeFactor
   3      |        3/4/2011    |       2
   3      |        4/5/2011    |       4
   3      |        5/5/2011    |       3
   4      |        3/21/2011   |       2
   4      |        4/10/2011   |       2
   4      |        5/10/2011   |       2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var TheQuery = (from list in TheList
                join fruit in MyDC.HarvestTimes on
                list.FruitID equals fruit.FruitID
                where ....
                select new MyObject{... }).ToList();
```

I'm have some trouble with the Where clause. **How do I get only the Fruit where the RipeFactor was always 2.** For instance, Fruit 3 has a RipeFactor of 2 but also has 4 and whereas only Fruit4 has only 2s. I tried with Contains but both fruits come up.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, buy try grouping by FruitID, Ripe factor, then count the number of rows on each FruitID group, if the count is 1 and Ripe factor is what you want then select it...

Comment: Is TheList filled from the same DataContext as HarvestTimes exists in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is a Relationship between the tables HaverstTime and Fruit:

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.HarvestTimes
    .Where(p => TheList.Select(q => q.FruitID).Contains(p.FruitID))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Fruit)
    .Where(p => p.All(q => q.RipeFactor == 2))
    .Select(p => p.Key);
```

This will create a `IEnumerable<Fruit>` which I think can be easily converted to MyObject.

Update:
Oops I forgot to add TheList.Select(q => q.FruitID). That's why it didn't compile.
Sorry =)

Update2:
Do the same, considering Ripefactor = 2 and 3

```
var TheQuery = MyDC.HarvestTimes
    .Where(p => TheList.Select(q => q.FruitID).Contains(p.FruitID))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Fruit)
    .Where(p => p.All(q => q.RipeFactor == 2 || q.RipeFactor == 3))
    .Select(p => p.Key);
```

Comment: Should it be .GroupBy(p => p.FruitID) ?

Comment: For some reason, the .Where(p => TheList.Contains(p.FruitID)) statement is underlined red.

Comment: It depends. I thought you wanted to select the Fruit object, not the FruitID. In that case you can do GroupBy(p => p.FruitID), it should work too.

Comment: ok, what if I want to select the RipeFactor where it's only 2 AND 3 (but never 1, 4 or any other value)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
var fruit = (from list in TheList
             join fruit in
               (from fr in MyDc.HarvestTimes
                group fr by fr.FruitID into fg
                where !fg.Any(f => f.RipeFactor != 2)
                select fg)
             on list.FruitID equals fruit.Key
             select new MyObject{... }).ToList();
```

Update - If you only want to return the distinct list of FruitIDs you need to select fg.Key instead of fg

```
var fruit = (from list in TheList
             join fruit in
               (from fr in MyDc.HarvestTimes
                group fr by fr.FruitID into fg
                where !fg.Any(f => f.RipeFactor != 2)
                select fg.Key)
              on list.FruitID equals fruit
              select new MyObject{... }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that works in the sense that it only returns Fruit4. I looked at it again and then I realized that it was returning all the Fruit4 records instead of just one. I think I wasn't clear on that, my bad. Would .Single work i this case?

Comment: @frenchie - Updated the answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'll just take the one with duplicates and delete the dups with a linq-to-object query. Thanks for your help and if you figure out why duplicates are showing then please let me know.

Comment: Quick follow-up: what if I want results where RipeFactor is only 2 AND 3? Should this do it: where !fg.Any(f => f.RipeFactor != 2 && f => f.RipeFactor != 3) ?

Comment: @frenchie - not sure why duplicates are being shown. Yes you are right